# Can't remove codeigniter's index.php in a subfolder of a wordpress site on root

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm aware of a lot of solutions around there, and tried everything. The problem is, when I put a `.htaccess` in the codeigniter subfolder, it's not read. I thinks it's because of the `AllowOverride` directive, but I can't change that.

I tried to skip the main subfolder that is not part of wordpress, one I called "sandbox", in the root `htaccess` (that's part of wordpress), so it doesn't "inherit" any problem from that rewrite (for example, to not have 404 managed by wordpress in the codeigniter project).

The problem is, as I said, that the .htaccess in the /sandbox/ciproject/ folder is not read. So, I tried this in the main .htaccess, and it worked... for a little time.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?sandbox/
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteBase /sandbox/ciproject/
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|img|fonts)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

That allowed me to make it work for a while... but it's not working anymore. Something more I could try? I already changed the config of the codeigniter project so it doesn't use index.php, but nothing. I only get a server error 500 now, and if I delete the second half of the htaccess, I only get 404 as a response for getting rid of the index.php

I don't know if I'm losing some data, but just ask and I'll edit this, so you're not blind at this one.

Comment: Still the same, error 500 around there...

Comment: On what urls are you getting the 500 ISE and what urls are working?

Comment: On every URL of the domain. This htaccess is on the root, after all, and something must be wrong with the second half, something must be wrong, but I'm far from an expert in htaccess directives, so I don't know what's causing the error 500

Comment: which folder is your wordpress served from?

Comment: The WordPress is at the root, and I have a subfolder, which I ignore in the WordPress htaccess to don't let it affect it (and it works fine), and inside a subfolder, inside that subfolder is the codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, your code-ignitor part doesn't work because, you have two clashing rewrite rules in your htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

These are a clashing rule set. Remove one of the lines and then try. It should work.

Comment: I tried, didn't worked... but combining both your answers, it did! I removed the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]` and used the lines from above.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use only this code in htaccess  file 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sandbox/ciproject/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: I tried that vefore this, and didn't worked... but, I don't exactly know how, now I've tried with the conds you've put, and the `RewriteRule` I had already (`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]`) and now, it works fine! Thanks a lot for making me try it again!